# How to transform given points using dilation and translation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> A transformation can combine a dilation and a translation. For example, under the transformation **(x,y) to 3(x,y) + (5,8),** the point P(-5,4) corresponds to the point P'(-10,20). Under this composition of transformations, what does the point R(4,3) correspond to? The point S(2,-4)?

What do I even do for this? Plug in the given points (5,8) to x and y respectively? But I don't think that's how I get the right answer. How do I do it? Dilation means to multiply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation can be written more clearly when separated:

$$ x' = 3x + 5 $$
$$ y' = 3y + 8 $$

In the example they give, $ P(-5, 4) $ would be treated as:

$$ P_{x'} = 3\cdot(-5) + 5 = -10 $$
$$ P_{y'} = 4\cdot(4) + 8 = 20 $$

Then it is obvious that $ P'(P_{x'}, P_{y'}) = P'(-10, 20) $.

Dilation refers to the expansion of the set via multiplication.

Comment: So separating them and and plugging in the given points would give me the points?

Comment: Yes, this is a common practice in early stages of linear algebra, in say high school. In university you would move onto matrices.